# B2C published scopes - "No identifier URI has been provided"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to set this up but when going to Published Scopes tab for the client app I have created I am unable to configure as am receiving this message "No identifier URI has been provided", can anyone advise pls?

Comment: Hi @Journeyman1234. Is this for the client app or the resource app? For a client app, you should be configuring "API access" rather than "Published scopes".

Answer (score 1):

As @Chris Padgett said, if it's client app, you should configure "API access" rather than "Published scopes" to grant a client app permissions. For more details, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens#grant-a-native-or-web-app-permissions-to-a-web-api. Hope it will be helpful!

Comment: When I follow this guide and get as far as selecting an API, there is none available. I've only created a client app so far under B2C, the API I want to authorise was created under the Active Directory and exists under the same subscription but does not appear? The api endpoint I want my client to have access to is listed as the Reply URL within the client app properties. not sure where else it needs to go in order to be linked?

Comment: I am afraid that you aren't able to use the client app under B2C to have access to the API created in the Azure ad. You can register a client app in the Azure ad to have access to the API under the Azure ad or register an API in the Azure ad b2c. For more details, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration.